# Starting AWS Serverless Framework can't install starter sample

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I want to run the [serverless framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) for use with my AWS solution.

But the sample starter is not installing properly, why?

```
$serverless project install serverless-starter

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:5
let argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: what version of node do you have installed? are you using at least version 4.x?

Comment: @Mikelax good point, i was running a very old node version, upgraded now working Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As solved in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883864/starting-aws-serverless-framework-cant-install-starter-sample#comment63227209_378838640), the issue occurred when a old Node version was used and Serverless requires Node version **4.x** or greater.

In this case, the `let` declaration was not recognized because it's a ES6 specification and support started only in Node 4 ([Kangax table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)).